# Magento 2 : Add extra "Proceed to Checkout" Button on top of grid on shopping cart page

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart

On the shopping cart page, there are a proceed to checkout button display after order summary. I want to display also before the shopping cart grid.

How to display it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this below code for display button on top of grid on shopping cart page :

> **app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.top" template="Vendor_Module::onepage/link_top.phtml" before="checkout.cart" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> **app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/templates/onepage/link_top.phtml**

```
<?php
/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Link */
?>
<?php if ($block->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()) :?>
    <button type="button"
            data-role="proceed-to-checkout"
            title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Proceed to Checkout Top')) ?>"
            data-mage-init='{
                "Magento_Checkout/js/proceed-to-checkout":{
                    "checkoutUrl":"<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getCheckoutUrl())) ?>"
                }
            }'
            class="action primary checkout<?= ($block->isDisabled()) ? ' disabled' : '' ?>"
            <?php if ($block->isDisabled()) :?>
                disabled="disabled"
            <?php endif; ?>>
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Proceed to Checkout Top')) ?></span>
    </button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Clean cache and check it.

Comment: Working as expected..

Comment: good one!.... :)

Comment: Thank you !! Happy Coding !!

Answer (score 0):

Create `checkout_cart_index.xml` at

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

==========**OR**==========

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="cart.summary">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.top" template="{Vendor}_{Module}::onepage/link_upper.phtml" before="-" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create `link_upper.phtml` at

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/templates/onepage/link_upper.phtml

==========**OR**=========

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/templates/onepage/link_upper.phtml

```
<?php
/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Link */
?>
<?php if ($block->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()) :?>
    <button type="button"
            data-role="proceed-to-checkout"
            title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Proceed to Checkout Top')) ?>"
            data-mage-init='{
                "Magento_Checkout/js/proceed-to-checkout":{
                    "checkoutUrl":"<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getCheckoutUrl())) ?>"
                }
            }'
            class="action primary checkout<?= ($block->isDisabled()) ? ' disabled' : '' ?>"
            <?php if ($block->isDisabled()) :?>
                disabled="disabled"
            <?php endif; ?>>
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Proceed to Checkout Top')) ?></span>
    </button>
<?php endif?>
```

**Note:** You may need to adjust design of upper checkout button

Hope above will help!

Comment: Nope. It's not proper working. It's display inside order summary. I want bottom of the title or beside title.

Comment: It is working...you just need to change position using after before element!